# Dynamic Resource WPF Не удалось разрешить ресурс

Tags: wpf, локализация

Пытаюсь по [статье](https://habr.com/post/256193/) на хабре сделать локализацию на лету.

Создал 3 словаря ресурсов, и все остальное. Все в точности как в коде на статье кроме мелких моих деталей, и того что у меня без `DefaultLanguage`. Все вроде готово, но в `xaml` выводит вот такую штуку при использовании ресурсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Не удалось разрешить ресурс "reg_welcome".

### Вот сам элемент:

```
<Label
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Content="{DynamicResource reg_welcome}"
    FontSize="28"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="157,10,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Не могу понять что это значит. Хотя при запуске все работает нормально.

**Может в этом предупреждении есть закромный смысл? Что нужно изменить, что бы предупреждения не было?**

Comment: Почему вы используете Label для вывода текста? Это оверхед, есть TextBox. Почему вы используете для компоновки Margin? Используйте уже наконец панели. Ну и раз всё работает нормально, то причин волноваться нет, просто студия не может найти ресурс в дизайнтайме.

Comment: @АндрейNOP извините, а чем Label плох? TextBox, по-моему, для ввода текста. А для вывода Label мне подходит как раз

Comment: TextBlock, конечно же, а не TextBox, опечатался. А Label на самом деле это ContentControl и может содержать любой контент, в том числе картинки, любые другие контролы или панели с контролами

Comment: @АндрейNOP а как студии показать тот самый ресурс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нашёл несоответствие с рабочим проектом. Просто в App.xaml нужно было указать какой словарь ресурсов нужно использовать при запуске.

### Вот код App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="BrainTrain.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="Localization/lang.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```